# What is this connector type called?

Tags: connector

I am trying to build a custom pump controller circuit but can't figure out what this connector is called. Can anyone help identify it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=pin_socket_comm_matenlok_084&s=Commercial%20MATE-N-LOK%205.08) identifies it as a TE Commercial MATE-N-LOK.

You can buy them here: https://www.digikey.com/short/dncjj5vn

[image]

{[Source: TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/rectangular-power-connectors-commercial-mate-n-lok/YG2dEX25kx.html)}